# Understanding the relationship between HTTP Sessions and session cookies

Tags: session, cookies

I am just learning about how sessions work in a J2EE environment. Let's say that someone makes a GET request on MusicServlet, and I need to pull some data from their session, so I call:

```
request.getSession(false);  //if they don't have one, I don't want to create one
```

I am trying to figure out how the server knows which session belongs to me, since the request is essentially stateless, and there is only 1 instance of the MusicServlet that exists. Maybe I am mixing concepts. Is it the JSessionID cookie that is used to 'match' the user to their particular session on the server? Does that mean that if I clear my cookies, the session that belongs to me can't be retrieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you got it right - the random identifier in session cookie ties specific cookie in client browser to the session storage on the server side.

Whatever you set using [setAttribute()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) will be stored on **server side** and attached to the JSESSIONID. If the generally stateless client comes back with the same JSESSIONID, the server can retrieve its session from its storage and [getAttribute()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) will return previously stored values. If the cookie is lost, the session on the server becomes orphaned and will expire after some time.

P.S. it's not always the case that sessions are stored on server side - for example [Play framework stores them on client side](http://ipsec.pl/play-framework/2014/session-variables-encryption-play-framework.html).